# Непонятная для меня строчка кода

Tags: c++

```
int result = (round(coin * 0.1) * 10); // что делает этот фрагмент?? 
Помогите, вот целая програма...

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>`введите сюда код`
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct money
{
    int grn;
    short int coins;
    int count;

    static int Round(short int coin)
    {
        int result = (round(coin * 0.1) * 10);
        return result;
    }
    static double multiplication(double money, double coin, int Count)
    {
        int roundedCoin = Round(coin); // Заокруглюю копійки
        stringstream unite; // Об'єднав усі значення для знаходження ціни
        double value;
        unite << money << roundedCoin;
        unite >> value;
        double result = (value * Count) / 100; // Виконую множення ціни продукту на його кількість
        cout << "The price for product: " << money << "." << coin << "; Count: " << Count << "; Total product price: " << result << endl;
        return result;
    }
};

static void receipt(double price)
{
    cout << "The total price of the receipt: " << price << " grn.\n" << endl;
}

static double Sum(double value1, double value2)
{

    double result = value1 + value2;
    receipt(result);
    return result;
}
static string createFile(string value0, string value1)
{
    ofstream out;
    out.open("D:Lab1.txt");
    out << value0 << endl;// Заповнюю файл значеннями
    out.close();

    money value;
    ifstream in1("D:Lab1.txt");
    while (in1 >> value.grn >> value.coins >> value.count) {}// Отримую значення з файлу та присвоїв їх послідовно полям структури оператором ">>"

    double a = value.multiplication(value.grn, value.coins, value.count);


    out.open("D:Lab1.txt");
    out << value1 << endl;
    out.close();

    money value2;
    ifstream in2("D:Lab1.txt");
    while (in2 >> value2.grn >> value2.coins >> value2.count) {}

    double b = value2.multiplication(value2.grn, value2.coins, value2.count);
    Sum(a, b);
    return value1;
}
int main()
{
    createFile("19 89 3 ", "13 29 1"); // Створюю файл з числами ( вхідними даними ціни) 
}
```

Comment: Округляет целое число в ближайшую сторону до десятых. То есть `123` -> `120`, `128` -> `130`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков - прошу прощения, видно, еще не проснулся :-) я сам написал комментарий, и потом уже полез проверять, только что убедился, что да - работает round() именно как округление

Comment: @ПавелЕриков округление до десятков. до десятых - это дроби. `0.15` -> `0.2`

Comment: Всем большое спасибо)) 
Я студент и вы мне очень помогли

Answer (score 2):

Эта строка производит округление с точностью до десятков.

```
12 -> 10
5 -> 10
1 -> 0
```